# How to remove the table SQlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I create a table in a database, and when trying to overwrite the data, 
then **"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE CONTACT** can not remove the old table. What is wrong?

This my DBHeper class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "autowash";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATLNG = "latlng";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_SITY = "sity";
        public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "adr";
        public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
        public static final String COLUMN_BEGIN = "begin";
        public static final String COLUMN_ENDING = "ending";    
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "autowash.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT
                        + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_SITY + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_LATLNG + " REAL, "
                        + COLUMN_ADRESS + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_PHONE  + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_BEGIN  + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_ENDING + " TEXT  "
                        + ");";    

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }    
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
                onCreate(db);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: What's the problem, specifically? Note that onUpgrade() is not invoked if your database file was already the version you requested in constructor.

Comment: Why do you want to drop the table to override data?! Normally one uses DELETE for that...

Comment: `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;`

Comment: http://blog.adamsbros.org/2012/02/28/upgrade-android-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 1):

Increment your DATABASE_VERSION in the code. onUpgrade() will run only when there is a change in the DATABASE_VERSION on the device compared to one in the APK installed/upgraded/pushed.

Updated:
When you say data is new will the fields (SCHEMA) also change dynamically? If not all you have to do is remove records from SQLite table and not the table itself. If your data is so dynamic that JSON fields also change why not store the JSON itself in SQLite. Use a JSONParser/Reader to then process it.

Comment: The data are taken from JSON from server and each time may be new. How to update a table, without reinstall app?

Comment: The data is not so dynamic, it is enough to update them every time when open the app.

Comment: When I meant dynamically I meant with the fields in JSON change. I assume you have created SQLite SCHEMA to match the tags in JSON. So if Tags remain same and only their values change, all you do is remove old data (delete record) and add new one.

But if your tags also change overtime such that your SCHEMA become obsolete, then it would be best to store the JSON itself and in the DBhandler (read/write) class implement JSON parsing. 

Either ways, parse when you write or parse when you read.

Comment: I decided my problem so  this.deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
then parsing JSON and create a new database with the same name as the old.